# Google index spamming with our company name

Tags: seo, google-index, legal, blackhat

One of our competitors has somehow spammed our full company name into the Google index like this:

```
http://www.competitorwebsite.example/our-full-company-name/
```

When we visit the link, though, it goes to a "not found" page. Attempting the view the cached page from Google results in a 404.

The net result of this is that they are the 3rd organic result when our company name is searched. It *appears* they have a method for stuffing the index with our company name for their own benefit.

How did they do this, how do we prove it is intentional and deliberate, and is there anything that can be done to stop it?

Comment: The Google cache returning a 404 doesn't indicate anything nefarious.   The Google cache is having problems right now and we are getting tons of questions about why webmasters get 404 errors for their sites in the Google cache.

Comment: If you visit the URL on your competitor's website, do they actually have a page?  What does it say?

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It goes to the website's own "not found" page.

Comment: The link that leads you to the 'not found' page is from the search result?

Comment: @YousefAl-Hadhrami That's correct. I'm on their website right now, the URL is as shown above, and the page content is their website saying, "Page not found." Maybe they literally created that page and allow it to exist to spam the index?

Comment: if it's a 404 page not found header, then they probably of created a page with content earlier in the past and requested Google to crawler the pages/website so that it gets indexed in the search result, and after it got indexed, they changed the content to 404 not found page, *check something called crawling frequency*, so it will either get removed automatically when Google recrawls the site again or if you do it manually using the outdated content removal tool.

Comment: So even if they created a dozen of those 404 not found pages, they can't stay on the index forever, especially if you put some effort to remove them, try them with the way I mentiond or any other way you that you might find, it won't be much time until all of them gets removed from the index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the section regarding [Legal Removal Requests](https://support.google.com/legal/answer/3110420), after you read it to see under which category your issue relates to, if so then go down and press [Submit a Legal Request](https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905), it will take you through a wizard, where you can justify who, where and what's the reason. After maybe like 2 business days *(sometimes more)* you will get a response from Google stating if any what actions they performed regarding your request.

If you don't have the legal rights to remove it, all you can do is increase the [SEO](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35291) of your website so that you appear before your competitor on the search results.

As for the 'not found' 404 pages that they used using your company name that appears in the search, use the [content removal tool](https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/removals) to remove [outdated content](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6349986?hl=en), otherwise, it will be removed automatically when Google crawler indexes your competitor site again *([crawling frequency](https://support.google.com/news/publisher-center/answer/40392?hl=en) depends on how famous or important your competitor site is, it might take 1-30 days)*